# Сделать привязку размера шрифта

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Получил задание по `Binding` (только начали учить), `INotifyPropertyChanged` использовать нельзя.

*Необходимо*:

1. Сделать привязку размера шрифта на кнопках к размерам формы(чем больше форма тем больше шрифт и наоборот).

Вот как это получилось у меня, но работает оно не совсем правильно, да увеличивает и уменьшает, но не пропорционально как то.

Подскажите как поправить данную ситуацию?

```
 private void TextButtonChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewSize.Width > e.PreviousSize.Width && e.NewSize.Height > e.PreviousSize.Height)
        {
            foreach (var obj in grid.Children)
            {
                if (obj is FButton)
                {
                    var btn = (FButton) obj;
                    if (btn.FontSize < 24)
                    {
                        btn.FontSize++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var obj in grid.Children)
            {
                if (obj is FButton)
                {
                    var btn = (FButton)obj;
                    if (btn.FontSize > 8)
                    {
                        btn.FontSize--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если в % указать высоту формы и размер шрифта? если высота формы 150%, то шрифт тоже 150%

Comment: Контейнеры вы можете использовать?

Comment: Контейнеры можно

Comment: Делайте конвертер масштаба и привязывайтесь к ActualWidth/ActualHeight окна через этот конвертер

Comment: что то я не до конца понимаю, что такое "конвертер маштаба" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему вот таким образом, все пропорционально.

```
class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            double height = (double)value;
            height = height / 10;
            return height;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

А в XAML вот так:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyValueConverter x:Key="myVC" />
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Hello World!" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource myVC}}"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```